# Copying S3 files from one account to another

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to simply copy some files from another S3 account to mine, but I am constantly facing the following error -

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the UploadPartCopy operation: Cannot access through this access point
```

I have added policies on the IAM user and the bucket for the required copy-paste operation-

IAM Policy (Destination User)-

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectTagging",
                "s3:PutObjectTagging"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:us-west-2:620889225884:accesspoint/bulian-ai-mdl-parquet-1-access-point/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:us-west-2:620889225884:accesspoint/bulian-ai-mdl-parquet-1-access-point",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bulian-ai-mdl-parque-eziseoueyefwzsncu4iwr13fgpocyusw2b-s3alias/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bulian-ai-mdl-parque-eziseoueyefwzsncu4iwr13fgpocyusw2b-s3alias",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mobilelocationfeed.parquet.usw2.onemata.com/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mobilelocationfeed.parquet.usw2.onemata.com"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObjectTagging",
                "s3:PutObjectTagging"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bulianai/",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bulianai/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Bucket Policy (Destination) -

```
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1611277539797",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1611277535086",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::864295014592:user/bulian_demo"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bulianai/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1611277877767",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::864295014592:user/bulian_demo"
            },
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bulianai"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am able to list the source files on the CLI therefore this account does have access to the source bucket, I am not quite sure what exactly the issue is over here.

Edit -

Source Bucket

```
s3://bulian-ai-mdl-parque-eziseoueyefwzsncu4iwr13fgpocyusw2b-s3alias/location_country=IN/output_year=2022/output_month=10/output_day=01/
```

Destination Bucket

```
s3://bulianai/OneMata/
```

Comment: You copy from where to where? The bucket policy is on source or destination? Sadly your question lacks details as is unclear.

Comment: Apologies @Marcin, I have updated the question.

Comment: @Anurag-Sharma were you able to resolve this one? I'm also stuck with the same error from onemata.

Answer (score 1):

1. Strange I have never seen such a usage of wildcards docs - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-with-s3-actions.html

   ```
     "s3:Get*",
     "s3:List*",
     "s3:Put*"
   ```
2. Your iam policy is missing permissions for source or destination bucket ( unclear what is source or destination)

   ```
     {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:GetObject"
          ],
          "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::source-DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET",
            "arn:aws:s3:::source-DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/*"
          ]
        },
        {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl"
          ],
          "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::destination-DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET",
            "arn:aws:s3:::destination-DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/*"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
   ```

Follow this https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/copy-s3-objects-account/

Comment: I have updated the question with the source and destination buckets

Comment: I have updated the bucket policy on the question, and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: What is the cli command you are using to copy?